# Can I omit “to be” in "I want you (to be) happy."?

Tags: sentence-construction, to-infinitive, implication

I want you (to be) happy.

I like you (to be) happy.

I hope you (to be) happy.

I protect you (to be) safe.

Can I omit “to be” in this way?

Comment: Yes for your first example (subject to context) where you can use just the adjective as a verbless clause, technically a 'small clause', but not for your other examples which are ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, *no*. "I want you happy," possibly, might be used, but not commonly. "I want you safe," would be acceptable.

And "I hope you to be safe," is not acceptable even with "to be."

If it's in the future, use, "I hope you *will be* safe."

If in the present, "I hope you are safe."

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot remove "to be" in any of those sentences and have the same meaning, and some of them are not grammatical either way.

"I want you to be happy" means I care about your future happiness.

"I want you happy" means you're not happy now and it upsets me. It sounds angry, demanding.

"I like you to be happy" is slightly unnatural, and means something like, "When you're happy, I like it. More natural would be "I'd like you to be happy", and it has the same meaning as the first one, "I want you to be happy"

"I like you happy" means I like you when you're happy.

"I hope you (to be) happy." Both of these sentences are bad grammar.

"I protect you to be safe" means I protect *myself* by protecting you.

"I protect you safe" is bad grammar.

Answer (score -1):

Yes , for the first two you can omit (to be)
I want you happy.
I like you happy.
(This is verified by google)
But for last two, I can't say because they dont look appropriate .